# can i configure cron job for localhost

Tags: php, mysql, cron

it's a one line question and i don't know how to describe it

```
mysystem config:-

os: windows Xp
server : Wamp server (latest)
```

is this posible ?

Comment: First, off-topic, voting for migration to SU. Second, Windows doesn't have a cronjob, it only has planned tasks.

Comment: i don't understand your first part of your comment

Comment: "SU" is http://superuser.com/ which is perhaps more appropriate for windows administration questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cron is a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like computer operating systems. Which means you can not configure it on Windows.

Comment: if i switched to linux can i set that

Comment: Sure. You can find basic information on Cron online everywhere. See for example http://serverfault.com/questions/162388/what-does-five-asterisks-in-a-cron-file-mean and http://aplawrence.com/BDD/bbcronbasics.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can,

simply go to task scheduler in windows

create a new task
  1. in the actions tab, navigate to the exe file of any web browser you have installed on your system
  2. in the arguments textbox, type the url to the script you wish to execute (e.g. localhost/mysite/cron.php).

This should start the browser automatically and run your php file

Answer (score 0):

Windows *does* have the `at` scheduler, which is pretty easy to use. Not as nice as `cron` for scheduling *repeating* tasks, last I looked at it, but it was easy.

Windows 7 has a [scheduled tasks framework](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569). It might be able to do what you need. It seemed pretty complicated to me, but it might be perfect.