# Setting a CRON job in VM (Vagrant) to run Codeigniter function?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I'm trying to create a CRON job in a Linux virtual machine (using Vagrant) that will run a PHP Codeigniter function every 10 minutes.

The Codeigniter project is located in the /var/www/ folder of the virtual machine.

I've tried many different variations of:

```
*/10 * * * *  /usr/bin/php /var/www/index.php cc processCCqueue
```

But nothing wants to work.  In my case, cc is the controller, and processCCqueue is the function I want to run in the cc controller.

I've also tried wget and curl with no luck for either.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I had a similar issue a while back, have you tried using the URL to the function you want to call? eg */10 * * * * www.example.com/processCCqueue?

Comment: I have.  The URL used to navigate to the project is http://127.0.0.1:8080.  I've tried variations of curl, wget, and lynx with that URL all with no luck :(

Comment: So it is a local project? What local server are you using? If it is wamp or something similar then you cant run cron jobs until it is on a linux server..If i remember correctly

Comment: See both of these questions for advice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028149/run-a-php-script-on-localhost-using-cron-job http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417639/can-i-configure-cron-job-for-localhost

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
 0/10 * * * * wget -O - http://127.0.0.1:8080 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Please consider adding at least some words explaining to the OP and to further readers of you answer why and how it does reply to the original question.